# Error 'cannot import name post_revision_commit'

Tags: python, django

Hi everyone I move my project, to a server I now I try to load the database 
`python manage.py loaddata resource/ddbb/20160817_db.json` 
 or even run the server but I obtain this error.

```
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .pagemodel import *  # nopyflakes
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 1453, in <module>
    _reversion()
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 1449, in _reversion
    exclude_fields=exclude_fields
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/helpers.py", line 135, in reversion_register
    from cms.utils import reversion_hacks
  File "/home/mxp1217/django1101/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/utils/reversion_hacks.py", line 18, in <module>
    from reversion.models import Revision, Version, post_revision_commit  # NOQA  # nopyflakes
ImportError: cannot import name post_revision_commit
```

This is my installation in my environment on the server

```
cmsplugin-filer==1.1.3
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.8.15
django-appconf==1.0.2
django-classy-tags==0.8.0
django-cms==3.4.1
django-filer==1.2.5
django-formtools==1.0
django-mptt==0.8.6
django-polymorphic==0.8.1
django-reversion==2.0.6
django-sekizai==0.10.0
Django-Select2==4.3.2
django-treebeard==4.0.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.5
djangocms-attributes-field==0.1.1
djangocms-column==1.7.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.5.2
djangocms-inherit==0.2.2
djangocms-installer==0.9.1
djangocms-link==2.0.1
djangocms-snippet==1.9.1
djangocms-style==1.7.0
djangocms-text-ckeditor==3.3.0
djangocms-video==2.0.2
djangorestframework==3.4.7
easy-thumbnails==2.3
feedparser==5.2.1
html5lib==0.9999999
MySQL-python==1.2.5
Pillow==3.4.1
pytz==2016.7
six==1.10.0
tzlocal==1.3
Unidecode==0.4.19
```

Any idea How I can solvent this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be on latest `djnago-reversion`. Because `post_revision_commit` signal has been removed since 2.0.0 and added back in the latest version. [Reference](http://django-reversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html?highlight=post_revision_commit#signals)

Comment: Hi @Sagar How to know my version of djnago-reversion, why I don't see when execute pip freeze

Comment: From your requirements file i can see it's `django-reversion==2.0.6`. Try updating it with latest and check. Hope that works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `django-cms` version you are using doesn't support `django-reversion` 2.0+.  The comments in the [django-cms source](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/3.4.1/cms/utils/reversion_hacks.py#L3) seem to affirm this.  I would try installing the latest 1.x version of `django-reversion` and see if that doesn't work.